# How could Cerberus defend Hell effectively?

Tags: mythical-creatures

Think sabretooth are scary now think thrice, this creature overwhelmed any or all the big cat that have or ever will exist. My questions is how can this hell hound use it's motor cortex simultaneously on all fours? does it experience alien paw syndrome?

Comment: it's a magic hellhound.

Comment: @Kreiri I can't upload growling sound so allow me to paraphrase for you: "meow!"

Comment: Only head runs the body at a time, the other heads can attack and one head sleeps.

Comment: @user2617804 so does it sleep rollover(sleepwalking) too?

Comment: Its like a dolphin- they sleep half a brain at a time.

Comment: [Most depictions of Cerberus](https://www.google.com/search?q=cerberus&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=NAaIVaLzPMG6sQG-j4CIDw&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1126&bih=788) look more canine than feline.

Comment: @Philipp all of the creature depicted in these pictures are hot, especially the one on fire.

Answer (score 3):

When I understand your question correctly, you seem to want to ask how the brains of a creature with multiple heads work. This applies not just to Cerberus but also to other mythological creatures like hydras.

I see four possible options:

- The heads don't contain any brain matter. The brain is somewhere in the body. The creature could lose all its heads and would still be able to survive (though not for long because besides the blood loss and trauma it is now unable to eat or drink).
- The creature has one "main head" which controls its body. The other heads either contain no brain at all or a lesser brain which only controls that head. Severing the secondary heads would not kill the creature, but severing the main head would. When the secondary heads are intelligent, the heads might have distinct personalities which might disagree with each other, although the main head would be the dominant one because it controls the body.
- The brain is distributed over multiple heads. The brain masses in the individual heads are connected through the spinal marrow and communicate with each other to form one consciousness, similar to how the left and right hemisphere of the human brain communicate. Severing one or more heads might affect its neural abilities more or less, similar to brain damage in humans.
- All the heads contain a fully functional brain, and they all have full control over the body. Over the aeons the heads have learned to coordinate very well, so an observer wouldn't even notice that there are multiple consciousnesses sharing the body. Because the heads are fully redundant, the creature can lose all heads but one and still retain full control over the rest of its body.

Comment: For the fourth bullet: I could also imagine a biological "lock", where only one head can be in charge of the body at a time. Either the lock has to be voluntarily given up, or the head with the most "will" controls the body at that time. This means if one head suddenly sees a trespasser he may grab control and attack, but otherwise there would probably be a naturally dominant head.